# Actionscript3 static variables inside functions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Can i do this in actionscript 3? counter should be defined only one time when calling timer function

```
function timer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    static var counter=1;
    trace("Times: " + counter );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about:

```
function timer(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    this.counter = this.counter || 0;
    this.counter ++;
    trace("Times: " + this.counter );
}
```

Comment: @Alex this line: `this.counter = this.counter || 0;` checks whether counter is defined in the scope that timer function running in , and uses it in case it is defined or creates a new one if it isn't defined. after this simply incrementing it..